# mod_rewrite from base of a domain

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to use mod_rewrite like so:

http://abc.com/something => http://abc.com/script.php?q=something

This doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /script.php?q=$1
```

Is it possible to do?

**Edit:**
I should mention mod_rewrite is working fine when I use this for example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule script/(.*)$ /script.php?q=$1
```

**Edit Again:** http://emailsms.me/redirect.php?id=abc

Using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-z]{1,})$ /redirect.php?q=$1
```

So theoretically http://emailsms.me/abc should be outputting abc (all it does is echo the input at the moment). but instead I get a 404 error.

**Update**: It seems as though Options +FollowSymLinks is causing the problem here. If I comment it out I get a 404 error but when its there and I put anything (I mean anything even a #) I get this error in my logs:

```
[Fri Oct 14 02:20:26 2011] [alert] [client 1.2.3.4] /home/me/redirects/.htaccess: Illegal option #
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` installed and loaded into Apache?

Comment: Yes it is. I can do normal redirects like: RewriteRule script/(.*)/$ /script.php?q=$1 but the one in my question gives me a 500 error.

Comment: Can you take a look at Apache logs? What do they say when you make a request to that page?

Comment: At the moment I'm seeing this: /home/me/redirects/.htaccess: Illegal option RewriteEngine

Comment: Illegal Option means it thinks you've given an unrecognized parameter to the "Option" directive. Do you have a stray "Option" in your htaccess?

Comment: Probably that means that you are not allowed to use certain Apache directives from your local `.htaccess` file. Try to add `AllowOverride All` in your `VirtualHost` section to discard that.

Comment: Or better, if mod_rewrite is already loaded, put `RewriteEngine on` in `VirtualHost` configuration instead of there in the `.htaccess`

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The server is a minimally configured cPanel installation on CentOS. My other accounts use the Option directive without problems (don't use those accounts for the same thing). You can find a copy of the .htaccess at http://emailsms.me/htaccess.txt

Comment: I should mention I commented out Options +FollowSymLinks because I get a 500 error otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You probably don't want the trailing forward slash in your rewrite rule, and you need to check that the requested file doesn't exist (the 2 RewriteCond lines) otherwise you'll get a 500 Server error because the rewrite loops (/script.php will ALWAYS match ^(.*)$ and get rewritten again). Note that if you don't have a /script.php file, you'll get a 500 error because the rewrite will loop.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing this from .htaccess, rather than vhost configuration. In that case you must lose the first / in your RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-z]{1,})$ /script.php?q=$1
```

It crashes with the (.*) as you can see

Comment: A 404 error when I use this. Have a look at my original question for the real world example.

Comment: If you get a 404, it doesnt find the php file in my opinion o.o

Comment: If you visit the url directly you can see its there: http://emailsms.me/redirect.php?id=asd

Comment: I cannot visit the url anyway.

Comment: What do you see? I see what I'm supposed to which is whatever you put in id ex. http://emailsms.me/redirect.php?id=something will show the word something.